# How can I get the incoming value of a property that is calculated from related objects in a model's clean method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I have two models, an Invoice model and a LineItem model.
The LineItem model looks like this:

```
class LineItem(models.Model):
    unit_price = models.DecimalField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)

    @property
    def lineitem_total(self): return self.unit_price * self.quantity
```

The Invoice model also has a `total` property, which returns the sum of the total of all of the related line items.

Now, when the line items related to an invoice get updated, I need to validate if the `total` property on the Invoice exceeds a certain maximum value. However the `clean()` method on the Invoice fires before the related line items get updated, so it still returns the old value. I need the validation to happen on the model itself rather than a form.

Is there a way to validate the line items?

I've tried putting the validation in the `Invoice` model's `clean()` method, however the `total` property still returns the old value before the line items are updated. 
I've also tried raising a `ValidationError` in the `Invoice` model's `save()` method, however that returns a `500` error.

Comment: Is there any relationship between Invoice and LineItem? Can you share the model for Invoice please?

Comment: Yes there is, sorry, I forgot to add that to my original question. The Invoice and LineItem models have a one-many relationship (one Invoice with multiple LineItems)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this in the `LineItem` model form (explanation in code comments):

```
class SomeFormItem(forms.ModelForm):
   ...
   def save(self, commit=False):
       instance = super().save(commit=False)
       total = instance.invoice.total  #  get total of line items (assuming used using reverse query)

       if self.instance.pk and ('quantity' in self.changed_data or 'unit_price' in self.changed_data):  # if we are editing already existing lineitem and total has been changed
           total += (self.cleaned_data['unit_price'] - self.data['unit_price']) * (self.cleaned_data['quantity'] - self.data['quantity'])  # self.cleaned_data contains new information and self.data contains old information and calculating the difference only
       else:
           total += self.cleaned_data['quantity'] * self.cleaned_data['unit_price']

       if total  > SOME_NUMBER:
            raise ValidationError()
       return super().save(commit=commit)
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.has_changed).